# Uber button web API requests

Tags: win-universal-app, uber-api

I need to develop the new [Uber button](https://devblog.uber.com/tap-a-button-get-a-ride-from-every-app/) for Windows 10 (Universal apps), and I wanted to know what are the web apis involved in the process.
I know I can clone Android or iOS SDKs and try to find the code, but since the uber team is actively monitoring the uber tag here I wanted to take a change.

Comment: not about programming? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can deep link into the Windows Phone app or mobile website by following the deep linking instructions on https://developer.uber.com/docs/deep-linking.